# Removing elements from arbitary columns in a Matrix in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

Suppose I have a matrix in MATLAB.

```
>> m = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9]

m =

     1     2     3
     4     5     6
     7     8     9
```

I have a list of indices, and I would like elements at those indices to be removed from the matrix.

The indices may belong to any arbitrary row or column. However, I can guarantee that if I were to remove an element from a row, I must remove an element from all other rows.

Once all the elements are removed, any "gaps" in the matrix should be addressed by shifting elements to the left.

```
% for example, removing m(1, 1), m(2, 2), m(3, 3) should yield
m =

     2     3
     4     6
     7     8

% it will NOT yield the following because the elements were shifted up, not to the left.
M =

     4     2     3
     7     8     6

% removing only m(1, 1) would also be invalid, 
% because I must remove an element from all other rows.
```

What would be the most efficient way to perform this operation for arbitrary number of indices?

Comment: The question is ambiguous in that you don't really define what you mean by a "valid matrix".  Would the solution, `[4,2,3;7,8,6]` also be a valid solution?  Are you guaranteed to remove the same number of elements from each row and from each column?

Comment: @Dave I see what you mean. I didn't consider that at first, thanks for bringing it to my attention. I clarified my question. Hopefully that removes the ambiguity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you need the elements shifted up, the solution is a two-step one.  First transpose the matrix, remove the corresponding elements, and then reshape and transpose the result.  (If shifting up were allowed, then you wouldn't need to transpose).  Assuming the indices are stored in a matrix, `remove`, then:

```
m=[1,2,3;4,5,6;7,8,9];
remove=[1,1;2,2;3,3];
copy=m.';
width=size(copy,2);
copy(sub2ind(size(copy),remove(:,2),remove(:,1)))=[];
m=reshape(copy,[],width).'
```

I think that solves the problem...